# Modelos fit para cálculo de meta-regressão no R Studio

Tags: r

Eu comecei a usar o R Studio a pouco tempo para fazer uma análise de meta-regressão utilizando o package mada.
Eu preciso criar um modelo fit para cada variável e depois de criar 6 modelos fit o R começou a dar um erro falando que não está encontrando o objeto.
Alguém como me ajudar?
Tem um limite de valores fit que podem ser criados?
Obrigada

Comment: Você conseguiria colocar o código que você está rodando? Vai ficar mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: A sequência que estava usando é essa: > madad(cbct.pr.sa)
> summary(fit.cbct.pr.sa.Metodo)
> summary(cbct.pr.sa$Metodo)
> fit.cbct.pr.sa.Metodo <- reitsma(cbct.pr.sa,
+ formula = cbind(tsens, tfpr) ~ Metodo)
mas agora já na segunda linha dá o erro de objeto não encontrado mesmo com o arquivo que anteriormente rodava o teste corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você rodou isso no `R`

```
> madad(cbct.pr.sa) 
> summary(fit.cbct.pr.sa.Metodo) 
> summary(cbct.pr.sa$Metodo) 
> fit.cbct.pr.sa.Metodo <- reitsma(cbct.pr.sa, + formula = cbind(tsens, tfpr) ~ Metodo)
```

Seu código parece ter vários problemas:

1. Na primeira linha você não atribui o resultado da função a nenhum objeto. Por isso, depois o summary não irá funcionar.
2. A ordem de execução parece estranha, você pede o `summary` de um objeto que é criado depois.

Veja se dessa forma funciona:

```
summary(cbct.pr.sa$Metodo) 
fit.cbct.pr.sa.Metodo <- reitsma(cbct.pr.sa, formula = cbind(tsens, tfpr) ~ Metodo) 
summary(fit.cbct.pr.sa.Metodo)
```

Não consegui identificar qual a finalidade do `madad(cbct.pr.sa)` no seu código.
Não existe nenhum limite de `fits` que podem ser criados.

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigada pela ajuda mas acho que é um problema mental meu. Não sei o que estou fazendo mas não estou conseguindo rodar os comandos.